# How to correctly renew ADAL authentication token for Server to server call

Tags: azure-active-directory, adal, microsoft-graph-api

In my scenario, the user grants permission for my AAD application to read their email from time to time in a server process using the Microsoft Graph API. At the time the user grants permission, I am getting a token using authContext.GetAuthorizationRequestURL and authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync. Thereafter, whenever I need an access token, I execute the following:

```
    TokenCache tokenCache; // deserialized
    AuthenticationContext authContext = CreateAuthContext(authority, tokenCache);
    AuthenticationResult authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(
            resource, 
            new ClientCredential(clientId, clientKey));
    return authResult.AccessToken;
```

Unfortunately calling MS Graph APIs with the resulting accesstoken returns a 403(Forbidden).

I get the impression I am not calling the right flavor of AcquireToken*() with the right information. Anyone familiar with this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The overload of AcquireTokenAsync indicated in the question will fetch an app-only token. An overload of AcquireToken that accepts ClientCredential and UserIdentifier parameters is what is needed, but unfortunately, such an overload does not exist.

However, you can keep using the access token till it expires (check using AuthenticationResult.ExpiresOn) and then use AuthenticationResult.RefreshToken with AcquireTokenByRefreshTokenAsync API to get new a access token.

Comment: Cool, thanks. I did figure out about the app-onliness of the token. I ended up getting my code to work by creating and passing also a UserAssertion, composed from: the previous access token, the username, and the cryptic string: `'"urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer"` . It seems to work. Can you comment on the validity of that solution?

Comment: That didn't actually work for me at all. At the present time, I seem to have a solution that works that involves using AcquireTokenUsingRefreshToken().